# Where is class library (package) in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add a class library (package) to my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. But I cannot find the option for some reason.

[image]

Is there some other dependency I have to install to get the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now called "Class Library (.NET Core)".

Comment: And I guess the name will change again at least five time over the next three years.

Comment: This project type doesn't output the nuget package by default. Is there a different project type that does?